# Achartengine Line graph Customization , need source code for v-0.7

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I need to customize Achartengine Line graph to plot Patients PT-INR readings. each point need to be different color based on reading(critical, normal, high).
so I downloaded from svn source done with customization now working fine. but

```
renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
```

is not showing reading at some points.

Screen shot [image: screen shot with using Achartengine versions 1.2]

Note : I had tried with Achartengine versions 1.2/1.1/1.0 jar files
but working fine with Achartengine version 0.7 jar

is this a bug, please help me to fix this issue or provide link to source code Achartengine versions 0.7

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found the answer. I noticed that when I tried to zoom Graph , the values of every points are showing. so I set view port for X-axis, 7 values at a time. which worked for me.

```
setXAxisMax(7);
```

Thanks to every one who tried to help.

[image]